# How to set dxe drivers loading sequence?

Tags: uefi, edk2

As far as i know DXE dispatcher first loads the driver that specifed in Apriori file. Then loads other considering dependencies.
I want to load utility either before AMITSE or after. If after AMITSE then the idea was CreateEvent(EVT_SIGNAL_EXIT_BOOT_SERVICES, ..., MAINFCN,...), but in MAINFCN i can't process other events.
Maybe a better stategy would be to load an UEFI_APPLICATION when received EVT_SIGNAL_EXIT_BOOT_SERVICES?

The main problem that i want to solve is execution driver between AMITSE screens (invite to press keys to enter setup and setup screen).

So i tried:

1. Put driver in different location in volume - didn't solve problem (driver loads after AMITSE invite screen).
2. Put TRUE in [depex] section - driver didn't loaded at all.
3. CreateEvent(..) - can't process other events (to catch keypress).

Didn't tried:

1. Driver that would raise a event to load an app before exeting boot services.

Maybe there are easier ways?

Answer (score 1):

Solved by writing driver that suggest to run an app.

Idea to create event and catching EVT_SIGNAL_EXIT_BOOT_SERVICES wouldn't work because after this [actually after ExitBootServices()] event several fields of the EFI System Table should be set to NULL. These include ConsoleInHandle, ConIn, ConsoleOutHandle, ConOut,
StandardErrorHandle, StdErr, and BootServicesTable. [UEFI Specification, Version 2.8 page 218-219]